# Using Filter() and index match to pull values from one sheet to another?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, unique, index-match

Link to problem spreadsheet [enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T1wbEMQCICFDtZZ-E7w2NPQMyu3B3pesY9BHk3Qmnmo/edit?usp=sharing)

I have a spreadsheet where I'm trying to build an overview tab that only shows the dates and values if there is data present for that date.

On my "Data Entry" tab, I have the following setup (I know this is not ideal but it's not allowed to change). Also I apologize, I don't know how to show merged cells through the stackflow tables, so I had to improvise.

|-------|----------------------> September
|-------|-------1st-------|-------2nd-------|

|-------| Avg | Min | Max | Avg | Min | Max |

| Ride 1| 76% | 24% | 95% | 57% | 12% | 91% |

| Ride 2| null | null | null | 75% | 62% | 99% |

**Then, on my Overview tab, I want the following**

| Ride 1 | Avg | Min | Max | Ride 2 | Avg | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1 | % | % | % | 9/2 | % | % | % |
| 9/2 | % | % | % |  |  |  |  |

I can't figure out a way to use the filter() function to pull in only the dates/values for each ride that have values.

I have tried the following =FILTER('Data Entry'!E7:GF7,if('Data Entry'!E6:GF6="Avg"),not(isblank('Data Entry'!E7:GF7)))

But am getting an error that the filter function must only be single row/column.

Any help on this would be appreciated